# Powershell Boolean Operators

Tags: powershell, if-statement, boolean

I am looking to create a Boolean script that alerts when certain certificates are set to expire [see the example of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOhuA.png).

I was looking at alerts for greater than 90 days out, 89 to 61 days out, 60 days to 31 days out, and less than 30 days out. Alert verbiage is not a big concern right now.

I understand I will need more, but looking to help on this elseif logic. I appreciate the help folks!

```
$Alert = 'TakeAction'

  If ($Alert  -gt '90')  {

       Write-Host "Licenses or Certificate are fine"

  }  ElseIf ($Alert  -lt '89' -AND -gt'61')  {

       Write-Host "Please contact Vendor for updated Licenses or Certificate information"

  }  ElseIf ($Alert  -lt '60' -AND -gt'31')  {

       Write-Host "Action must be taken to update Licenses or Certificate from Vendor"

  }  

}  ElseIf ($Alert  -lt '30' -AND -gt'1')  {

       Write-Host "Immediate action must be taken for renewal of Licenses or Certificate!"

  }  

Else {

       Write-Host "Certificate Information N/A"

}
```

Comment: 1) What's a 'boolean script'? Do you mean 'a script that uses boolean operators'? 2) Why are you quoting your numbers? Doing that will cause PowerShell to compare them as strings and not numbers. Is that your intent (and if so, why)?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart PowerShell compares based off the left hand object's type right? So if `$Alert` is an `[int32]` it'll try and convert them to numbers won't it?

Comment: Yes but 1) `$Alert` contains a string in OP's code, and 2) why add unnecessary quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one case where the `Switch` command shines. It tests against a case, and if true will execute the associated scriptblock. When the `Continue` command is used in that scriptblock it will skip the rest of the cases to test again.

```
Switch ($Alert){
  { $_ -gt 90}  {

       Write-Host "Licenses or Certificate are fine"
       Continue

  }
  { $_ -gt 61}  {

       Write-Host "Please contact Vendor for updated Licenses or Certificate information"
       Continue

  }  
  { $_ -gt 31 }  {

       Write-Host "Action must be taken to update Licenses or Certificate from Vendor"
       Continue

  }  
  { $_ -gt 1 }  {

       Write-Host "Immediate action must be taken for renewal of Licenses or Certificate!"
       Continue
  }  

    Default {

       Write-Host "Certificate Information N/A"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
($Alert -lt '89' -AND -gt '61')
```

You can't combine operators like that.  You need to have an operand on both sides of the expression.

Try this:

```
If ($Alert -gt '90') {
    Write-Host "Licenses or Certificate are fine"
}
ElseIf ($Alert -lt '89' -AND $Alert -gt '61') {
    Write-Host "Please contact Vendor for updated Licenses or Certificate information"
}
ElseIf ($Alert -lt '60' -AND $Alert -gt '31') {
    Write-Host "Action must be taken to update Licenses or Certificate from Vendor"
}
ElseIf ($Alert -lt '30' -AND $Alert -gt '1') {
    Write-Host "Immediate action must be taken for renewal of Licenses or Certificate!"
Else {
    Write-Host "Certificate Information N/A"
}
```

Note that you're using greater than (`-gt`) and less than (`-lt`) and not greater than or equal to (`-ge`) or less than or equal to (`-le`).  That seems like an possible bug.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple conditions `switch` is the way to go. If you would like alerts, I usually use `Send-MailMessage` to receive the alert. This will set `[boolean]$sendMail = $true` in order to evaluate if an email (notification) should be sent or not.

```
$certificateAge # = however you are getting your cert age
[boolean]$sendMail = $false
$message = @()
switch($certificateAge){
    {$_ -gt 90} 
    {
        $message = "Licenses or Certificate are fine"        
    }
    {$_ -lt 89 -and $_ -gt 61 } 
    {
        $message = "Please contact Vendor for updated Licenses or Certificate information"
        $sendMail = $true
    }
    {$_ -lt 60 -and $_ -gt 31 } 
    {
        $message = "Action must be taken to update Licenses or Certificate from Vendor"
        $sendMail = $true
    }
    {$_ -lt 30 -and $_ -gt 1 } 
    {
        $message = "Immediate action must be taken for renewal of Licenses or Certificate!"
        $sendMail = $true
    }    
    default{$message = "Certificate Information N/A"}
}


if($sendMail)
{
    Send-MailMessage -From CertAge@mail.com -To Admin@mail.com -SmtpServer mail.mail.com -Subject "Certificate information" -Body $message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to TheMadTechnician but more closely defining the ranges.

```
0..95|%{
    $Alert = $_
    switch ($Alert) {
        {1..30  -contains $_}   {"$_ Immediate action must be taken for renewal of Licenses or Certificate!" ;break}
        {31..60 -contains $_}   {"$_ Action must be taken to update Licenses or Certificate from Vendor" ;break}
        {61..90 -contains $_}   {"$_ Please contact Vendor for updated Licenses or Certificate information" ;break}
        {$_ -gt 90}             {"$_ Licenses or Certificate are fine" ;break}
        Default                 {"$_ Certificate Information N/A"}
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach, b/c the `-contains` operator is significantly slower than a simple `-gt` comparison.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the hint, does that also apply for `-in` ?

Comment: Yes. Both do a linear search on a list.